# Does the use of the "Camera Teleport" affects the Minimaxer Achievement?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

In Euro Truck Simulator 2, there is the following achievement:

> Minimaxer
>
> Gain 20,000 XP for several consecutive jobs with the total distance below 10,000 km

As you might know, there is a [Console](https://forum.scssoft.com/viewtopic.php?t=61852) available for the game that you can use by pressing the `/~ key (above tab, under esc). Once you enable the Console, you can teleport yourself with the free camera and F9 key.

Using this teleport function will revert or disable the achievement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Console use of any kind does not disable the ability to get achievements, in fact, you can abuse the console to get most of the achievements quite quickly. Mods do not effect achievements either.

Comment: I'm about to finish the achievement, once I confirm this the answer will be marked as accepted.

Comment: @Lemon did it work for you as well?

Comment: Yep, it did worked out.